import pandas error when running cron job
I am working on a virtual machine, and I am unable to run Python code using the cron scheduler without encountering an error related to import pandas as pd, even though I have installed Pandas and can run the code directly, as shown below.
Executing the code directly works as intended which means that Pandas is installed.
(myenv) (base) virtual-machine:~/myenv$ ./camera_job_run.sh
Copying gs://fi-local-camera-startup/localcamerastartup.py...
/ [1 files][  2.7 KiB/  2.7 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.7 KiB.                                      


[1464 rows x 7 columns]
Data written to development.test.camera successfully.
(myenv) (base) virtual-machine:~/myenv$ `

This is my code for camera_job_run.sh. I am copying the python file from cloud storage bucket.
Contents of camera_job_run.sh
#! /bin/bash
gsutil cp gs://local-camera/localcamerastartup.py /home//myenv
python3 /home//myenv/localcamerastartup.py`

My code for cron job
*/5 * * * * /home//myenv/camera_job_run.sh >> /home//myenv/camera_logfile.log 2>&1

The file is expected to run every 5 minutes and it is running, however, I am getting an error message related to import pandas.
I do not understand why it works directly when I execute the code but get an error using cron schedule.
Copying gs://local-camera/localcamerastartup.py...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  2.7 KiB]
/ [1 files][  2.7 KiB/  2.7 KiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.7 KiB.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//myenv/localcamerastartup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I have tried installing Pandas and running the code directly.

Activate the environment where you installed Pandas. Judging by your code, it's somewhere in "/home/.../myenv/...". To see what's going on, add import sys; print(sys.path, file=sys.stderr), run it twice (as you, and as a cron task), and compare the output.

BTW this type of error has already been discussed in detail here

My first guess is you didn't install pandas globally. But you shouldn't do that. Use virtualenv instead. Then in your shell script use the virtual env interpreter. So assuming you're on linux and create the virtual environment like this
python3 -m venv venv

and have activated it and installed pandas like this
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install pandas

you then wanna specify the path to the interpreter in your bash script when running the python script
/path/to/venv/bin/python3 localcamerastartup.py

where path to venv is the exact path to your virtual environment

myenv clearly is a virtualenv already, but the last point here stands: OP should use /home/myenv/bin/python3.
